# How to step using, in a C++ code, on a specif function inside the line

Tags: c++, gdb

In the following code:

```
 1 #include <iostream>
 2
 3 using namespace std;
 4
 5 int funcA(){
 6    cout << "A" << endl;
 7    return 1;
 8 }
 9
10 int funcB(){
11    cout << "B" << endl;
12    return 1;
13 }
14
15 int funcC(){
16    cout << "C" << endl;
17    return 1;
18 }
19
20 int funcAll( int a, int b, int c ){
21    return 1;
22 }
23
24 int main(){
25    cout << funcAll( funcA(), funcB(), funcC() ) << endl;
26    return 0;
27 }
28
```

Will be printed C, B, then A.

But when debuging and staying on line 25 if we command `next` on gdb the cursor goes to the line 26, if we command `step` gdb will step from funcC until funcA, but how to directly step on funcB OR funcA without setting a breakpoint or steping inside funcC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of evaluation of the arguments of a function in C and C++ is unspecified.  The compiler is free to reorder/interleave them however it sees fit, within certain constraints.  So you cannot rely on `funcC()` getting called before `funcA()`.

If you want to ensure that the arguments will get evaluated in a certain order, break them up into separate statements like this:

```
int a = funcA();
int b = funcB();
int c = funcC();
cout << funcAll(a, b, c,) << endl;
```

This will also make debugging easier.

If you don't want to rewrite your code, you still have some alternatives.  The easiest thing to do is just set a breakpoint inside your function of interest, e.g.:

```
break funcB
```

Or if you only need to do this once, use a `tbreak` instead of `break` to set a temporary breakpoint which will clear itself after it's hit for the first time.

You can also use the `nexti` and `stepi` instructions to step one assembly instruction at a time.  By looking at the disassembly with the `disassemble` command, you can step up to the appropriate call site (e.g. the `call` instruction on x86 or x86-64, or `bl` on PowerPC) using `nexti`, then `stepi` to step into it.  `stepi` and `nexti` work like `step` and `next`, except they operate on assembly instructions instead of lines of code.

Comment: Are you sure about the compiler dependent order? I thought that order must be made, because of the unlimited parameters list, just like when printf is used.

Comment: Yep.  C++03 §5.2.2/8 says: "The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. All side effects of argument expression evaluations
take effect before the function is entered. The order of evaluation of the postfix expression and the argument
expression list is unspecified."

Comment: Coding like that costs much for memory as a b and c will live until the end of the block. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: On the contrary, I'd be very surprised if there was any non-trivial memory usage difference between the two.  Unless you're compiling with optimizations disabled (in which case why do you care about memory usage?), the compiler will almost certainly produce nearly identical code -- it still needs to call `funcA`, `funcB`, and `funcC` in some order and save their results somewhere (either registers or on the stack) before calling `funcAll`.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any direct way to do this; the usual method is to set a breakpoint in the function of interest.

Comment: That's borying in some cases when funcC is not a 2 lines function... much to be loaded, sometimes some printing requiring a refresh if in TUI.

Comment: Yep. Debugging is hard; programming is harder.

Answer (score 1):

You step into C, then step out and step in to B

```
step
finish
step
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `until` command to run until you reach a specific line. It does not set a breakpoint, it only stops there once. See the [docs here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_38.html). (Specifically, see the docs on `until *location*`.)